# Undefined is not callable

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I'm writing a transaction which adds a participant and an asset to the network. Adding the participant to the network works, but when I try to access the Medical asset file registry the function returns undefined.

> Error: TypeError: undefined not callable

The logic of the transaction:

```
return getParticipantRegistry(namespace + '.Patient')
        .then(function (patientRegistry) {
            return patientRegistry.add(newPatient);
        }).then(function() {
            return getAssetRegistry('nl.epd.blockchain.MedicalFile');
        }).then(function (registry) {
            var medicalFile = factory.newResource(namespace, 'MedicalFile', "test");
            medicalFile.id = "test";
            medicalFile.owner = newPatient.bsn;
            medicalFile.mentors = [];
            medicalFile.permissions = [];
            medicalFile.allergies = [];
            medicalFile.treatments = [];
            medicalFile.medicine = [];

            // registry is undefined
            return registry.add(medicalFile);
        });
}
```

Models:

```
namespace nl.epd.blockchain

asset MedicalFile identified by id {
  o String                      id
  --> Patient                   owner
  --> Patient[]                 mentors
  o OrganisationPermission[]  permissions
  o Visit[]                   visits
  o String[]                  allergies
  o Treatment[]               treatments
  o Medicine[]                medicine
}

participant Patient identified by bsn {
  o String bsn
  o String firstName
  o String namePrefix optional
  o String lastName
  o String email
  o String telephoneNumber
  o String birthday
  o String gender
  o String city
  o String zipCode
  o String street
  o String houseNumber
  o String houseNumberExtra optional
}
```

NPM dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "fabric-ca-client": "1.0.0-alpha.0",
    "fabric-client": "1.0.0-alpha",
    "homedir": "^0.6.0",
    "composer-client": "^0.7.0",
    "composer-rest-server": "^0.7.0"
  }
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The assumption that the registry was empty was incorrect. The problem was that the owner wasn't a relationship. It was just a string, I thought that was allowed.

This caused the error described above.

The fix:

```
medicalFile.owner = factory.newRelationship(namespace, 'Patient', newPatient.bsn);
```